# We have $\triangle ABC$ and we must find $PM$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]

Here we have $\triangle ABC$ and some information related:
$$\angle A=60^\circ$$
$$\angle B=45^\circ$$
$$AC=8$$
$$CM=MB$$
The vertical line $PM$ is perpendicular to $BC$.
So now we want to calculate $PB$.
$$PB=?$$
I have tried some different ways to calculate it. But it was unsuccesfully not true.
What I tried was to calculate $\angle C=75^\circ$ and dividing the   $\triangle ABC$ into 4 pieces and try to find the side $PM$.like this:
[image]

Do you have any ideas? Please explain your answer briefly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

I would construct line $PC$ and show that $\angle APC$ is $90^\circ$.

After that I can use trigonometry to obtain $PC$ and I can use trigonometry one more time to obtain the length of $PM$.

Edit:

$PC$ is the line connecting $P$ to $C$. Notice that we have $PM = CM$. Then, we can compute $\angle ACP = 75^\circ - 45^\circ=30^\circ$. Hence $\angle APC = 90^\circ$. Hence $PC= AC \cos 30^\circ$.

Comment: @SiongTyeGoh can you improve your answer? Tell me first that how do you prove that $\angle APC$ is 90^\cirl? And also tell me how do i obtain length of $PM$??

Comment: I edited more info, can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks bro. Would you like to have a small discission?

Comment: sure if it helps?

Comment: Can you make a discussion room! I dont know how!

Comment: Yeah I think it surely helps me

Comment: I had just some questions related to the payment

Comment: I think it will take us less that 20 minutes.

Comment: Does this [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84908/we-have-triangle-abc-and-we-must-find-pm) work?

Comment: Are you ok with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84909/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-user602338).

Answer (score 0):

With the information of the second picture, you can calculate $CH$ and $PS$.

If you know $PS$, you know $HM$. Than $HM + CH = MB$

And $MB = PM$

Knowing $PM$ and $MB$ you can calculate $PB$